# Jssor slider working but not visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, jssor

I am trying to integrate the jssor slider into my website but for some reason it is not showing.

The slider should be showing on the right side of my site [(bflydev)](http://www.bflydev.be/nl), under the black gearwheel.

When inspecting the element I can clearly see the script working and the images sliding but none is showing.

I've tried z-indexes as well but without success.

Any tips to solve this mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly specify fixed size in pixel for `slides` container instead of `100%`.

please replace

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; max-width: 100%; height: 300px;">
```

with

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 276px; height: 300px;">
```